# Create an interval by multiples dates and sum a column

Tags: python, pandas, date

How can i create an interval of dates and sum the value of the dates that are in the interval? Those intervals must be grouped by Country.

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| Country | Population | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 1000 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-07-21 23:59:00 |
| UK | 800 | 2021-05-30 22:00:00 | 2021-06-02 19:00:00 |
| Spain | 1050 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-06-21 10:00:00 |
| France | 700 | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2022-01-15 10:00:00 |
| France | 750 | 2021-06-15 10:00:00 | 2021-06-17 19:00:00 |

And I need to create differents intervals for each contry to sum the population in each interval like this:

| Country | Population | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 1000 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-30 22:00:00 |
| UK | 1800 | 2021-05-30 22:00:00 | 2021-06-02 19:00:00 |
| UK | 1000 | 2021-06-02 19:00:00 | 2021-07-21 23:59:00 |
| Spain | 1050 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 | 2021-06-21 10:00:00 |
| France | 700 | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-06-15 10:00:00 |
| France | 1450 | 2021-06-15 10:00:00 | 2021-06-17 19:00:00 |
| France | 700 | 2021-06-17 19:00:00 | 2022-01-15 10:00:00 |

Any idea??

Thanks!

Comment: I think more information about what these "different intervals" are would be beneficial. For example: why you take the first value per country to fill with, and why Spain is unaffected.

Comment: I had not said it but the time intervals are grouped by country, as Spain has only one record, it is not affected since it only has one interval.